# metro error when running react native app from apk file

Tags: android, react-native

i have a react native app and im able to run it when i connect my phone and run the command react-native run-android but when i go to github and download the apk file from android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk and install the app i get this
[image]

i have android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but i dont know what else to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below commands to create debug apk

1.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

2. 

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```